# On tunneling to Israel after death

Tags: eretz-yisrael, funeral-burial-levaya, maseches-kesubos, jacob

I don't understand this passage in the Talmud:

> The righteous outside of Eretz Yisrael will be resurrected and roll [until they reach Eretz Yisrael]…  Rabbi Abba Salla Rava strongly objects to this: Rolling entails suffering for the righteous.  Abaye said: Tunnels are prepared for them in the ground.  Karna said… Our Patriarch Jacob knew that he was completely righteous, and that the dead outside of Eretz Yisrael are resurrected [anyway], so why did he trouble his sons [to bury him in Eretz Yisrael]? Because he thought he may not be worthy of the tunnels. ([Ketubot 111a](https://www.sefaria.org/Ketubot.111a.22?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))

If Jacob "knew" he was "completely" righteous, why would he worry that he "may not be worthy of the tunnels"?  What's the logic?

Comment: קטונתי מכל החםסדים ומכל האמת אשר עשית את עבדך

Comment: Nice question. It seems evident from the gemara that being *zocheh* to *mechilos* requires something else other than just being a *tzadik gammur*.

Answer (score 1):

See [Shlah, *Vavei ha'amudim*, *Amud ha'emes*, chapter 23](https://www.sefaria.org/Shenei_Luchot_HaBerit%2C_Vavei_HaAmudim.23.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en).

So, not going exactly with what he says (since he seems to have a different reading of the gemara), but using some of the ideas there:

I would posit, that in order for someone not to have *tzaar* when going through the *mechilos*, they must be on a level where the *shechinah* rests on their entire body. So this is more than being just a *tzadik gamur*, it is closer to the *madregah* of *ha'avos hein hein ha'merkavah*.

So Yaakov knew he was a *tzadik gamur* and would be *zocheh* to *techiyas ha'meisim* (whether this requires *mechilos* or whatever) but he did not know if the *shechinah* rested on his entire body, which is what is required one from *tza'ar gilgul mechilos*.

Comment: Why would you posit that?

Comment: @Rafael Based on the Shlah